# Sort contents of folder by their git time

Tags: linux, bash, ls, git

I want to sort the files in a folder by the time they were added to git.

I looked at [git ls-files sort by modification time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19362345/git-ls-files-sort-by-modification-time), but this gives me all the files in git by time. I want only the files/folders in that subdirectory.

For eg:

```
some-super-ls /my/git/repo/some/sub/directory
```

This should give me output similar to `ls` but sorted by date-time.
Is it possible?

Comment: `ls -lt` not good enough?

Comment: @Panki that uses the modification time in the current file system, not the last change time in the git repository.

Comment: What do you want to do with files which haven’t (yet) been added to the git repository, or which are ignored?

Comment: Maybe use `grep` to filter the `git ls-files` output?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A variant of [this answer to the linked question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54677384/4500798) lists all the files which are tracked, in the current directory, in reverse chronological order based on their last committed change:

```
git log --pretty='' --name-only | awk '/^[^/]*$/ { if (!seen[$0]++) print }'
```

Comment: Can it show timestamp?

Comment: If possible can you explain your answer too?

Comment: I can, but there’s a flaw in this approach, it only works in the root folder of a git repository. Let’s see if I can fix that first...

Comment: I think it works better without the /^[^/]*$/

Answer (score 3):

If `zsh` is an option, you could use its `oe` (or `Oe` depending whether you want newest-to-oldest or oldest-to-newest ordering) with a `git log` that returns the epoch time (`%ct`) of the most recent commit.

Ex.

```
print -rl *(Noe:'REPLY=$(git log -1 --format=%ct $REPLY)':)
```

To avoid having to remember and type the command, you could define a convenience function like

```
ct() { REPLY=$(git log -1 --format=%ct $REPLY); }
```

and then use

```
print -rl *(Noe:ct:)
```

This works by using a `zsh` *glob qualifier* of the form `oC`:

> oC
>
> specifies how the names of the files should be sorted.

in particular

> oe and o+ are special cases; they are each followed by shell code,
>   delimited as for the e glob qualifier and the + glob qualifier
>   respectively. The code is executed for each matched file
>   with the parameter REPLY set to the name of the file on entry and
>   globsort appended to zsh_eval_context. The code should modify the
>   parameter REPLY in some fashion. On return, the value of the parameter
>   is used instead of the file name as the string on which to sort.

---

References:

- [zshexpn: Filename-Generation](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Filename-Generation)

Comment: Can the timestamp be also shown?

Comment: If possible can you explain your answer too?

Comment: @NikhilWagh I can't think of a direct way to show the timestamp - maybe a more knowledgeable user will chime in? I have added a brief explanation.